# How to solve ambiguous cases when tracking text changes using diff algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, diff

I have been seeking an algorithm to trace edit changes between different versions of text. And I came up with this paper:[An O(ND) Difference Algorithm and its Variations](http://www.xmailserver.org/diff2.pdf)

However, I felt like the solution to diff algorithm might not be unique and might be unable to distinguish some ambiguous cases like:

version 1: a

version 2: aaab

So then diff algorithm won't be able to tell that the edit is whether, someone appended 'aab' at the end, OR , someone added 'a' at the begin and 'ab' at the end ..

So just wonder if there is another more precise algorithm. Or the best way is just to audit and save all the edit actions?

Comment: The question is if it matters what the user did when the end result is the same either way?

Comment: You can't tell the difference, because there *is* no difference.

Comment: Some problems don't have unique solutions (x+y=10). So?